# Issue with Segue image to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, segue

I've 2 VC :

The first VC **with 1 button** when tapped >> 2 options **post image form cam** or **library**

**Second VC** *chosen image* form VC1 segued to the second VC

I tried to figured This the error without any success

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   pointed at

```
  imageView.image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
```

I uploaded the project in dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/w7blbnyac9qyxgw/segImage.zip?dl=0

VC1

```
    class ViewController:UIViewController,UIAlertViewDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var btnClickMe: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var picker:UIImagePickerController?=UIImagePickerController()
    var popover:UIPopoverController?=nil

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        picker!.delegate=self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "" ) {
            let destVC : second = segue.destinationViewController as! second
            destVC.pics = imageView.image!
        }
    }

    @IBAction func btnImagePickerClicked(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let alert:UIAlertController=UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
            {
                UIAlertAction in
                self.openCamera()

        }
        let gallaryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallary", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
            {
                UIAlertAction in
                self.openGallary()
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel)
            {
                UIAlertAction in

        }

        // Add the actions
        picker?.delegate = self
        alert.addAction(cameraAction)
        alert.addAction(gallaryAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        // Present the controller
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
        {
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            popover=UIPopoverController(contentViewController: alert)
            popover!.presentPopoverFromRect(btnClickMe.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
        }
    }
    func openCamera()
    {
        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera))
        {
            picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            self .presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            openGallary()
        }
    }
    func openGallary()
    {
        picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
        {
            self.presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            popover=UIPopoverController(contentViewController: picker!)
            popover!.presentPopoverFromRect(btnClickMe.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
        }
    }
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {
        picker .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        imageView.image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController)
    {
        print("picker cancel.")
    }


}
```

second VC

```
class second: UIViewController {

var pics = UIImage()

@IBOutlet var image: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let img = UIImage(named: "pics")
    {
        self.image.image = img
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your storyboard wiring is wrong.

The image should really be set on an instance of `second` rather than an instance of `ViewController.`  Notice that the crash is happening in `ViewController` and not `second`

This code:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{
    picker .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    imageView.image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
}
```

is attempting to set an `imageView.image` in `ViewController`.  If you look at the Storyboard, there is no `UIImageView` in `ViewController`.

[image]

The way that you've defined `imageView` on `ViewController` is what makes this crash:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

With the `!` there, you are saying, "This will never be nil."  Well, that's obviously not the case because since this IBOutlet isn't wired to a `UIImageView` then it is nil.  And thus, when you try to access it, BOOM!

To fix this:

- Segue to `second` when the user picks an image
- Set the selected image on `second`'s `image.imageView` property

Other suggestion:
 - Use consistency in naming, eg second vs SecondViewController